# Elastic search script sort text as Number

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, search

I have an Elastic search field `ID` which is a Number but set in the index as a "text". I cannot change the index because of the huge volume of data to reload.
I am writing a script to do this sorting but getting a "Bad_request" error.

```java
Script script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", "ctx._source.ID.keyword", Collections.emptyMap());
ScriptSortBuilder.ScriptSortType sortType = ScriptSortBuilder.ScriptSortType.NUMBER;
builder.sort(SortBuilders.scriptSort(script, sortType).order(SortOrder.DESC));

searchRequest.source(builder);
response = restsearchClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

I have tried the following idorcode values: `doc['ID']`, `doc['ID.keyword']`, `ctx._source.ID`, `ctx._source.ID.keyword`.

---

please advice!

Comment: Can you check in your mapping if the keyword subfield was created for the com ID?
If the keyword subfield doesn't exist, I don't see any other way to re-index the index with a new mapping.

Comment: yes, Id.keyword is created

Comment: Can you show your query? I know your code is in java but seeing how the query is being generated will be important.
Since you said that the mapping has the ID.keyword a sort like this should work: ... "sort": [ { "ID.keyword": {"order": "asc" }}].

Answer (score 3):

If my understanding correct then you want to sort on number which is store as string and not as integer in Elasticsearch.

Below is sample Elasticsearch Query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "Number",
      "order": "desc",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
        String s = doc['ID.keyword'].value;
          int idvalue = Integer.parseInt(s);
          return idvalue;
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is Java code:

```java
Script script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", "String s = doc['ID.keyword'].value;int idvalue = Integer.parseInt(s);return idvalue;", Collections.emptyMap());
ScriptSortBuilder.ScriptSortType sortType = ScriptSortBuilder.ScriptSortType.NUMBER;
builder.sort(SortBuilders.scriptSort(script, sortType).order(SortOrder.DESC));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sagar, This worked...i had to change to "source": "Long.parseLong(doc['ID.keyword'].value)"

Comment: @vens great to know it helps you !! You can mark answer as solution.